# Populate a 2-D array with data from a table in VBA

Tags: html, arrays, vba, excel, html-table

I am trying to write data from a html table into a 2-D array, "htmlArr", I have created in VBA. I can get it to populate the first row of data (with all the correct column entries going across) using 2 for loops however the code breaks down after this and will not move to the next j to write the data in the second row.

Here is the part of my VBA code to populate the array:

eleColtr.Length = 11 & numberofColumns.length = 23

```
ReDim htmlArr(0 To (eleColtr.Length - 1), 0 To (numberofColumns.Length - 1)) 'set array dimensions 11 rows by 23 columns
    For j = LBound(htmlArr, 1) To UBound(htmlArr, 1)  'loop through rows dim 0 - 10 (html table indexes)
            Set ObjTr = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr")(j)
            For k = LBound(htmlArr, 2) To UBound(htmlArr, 2) 'loop over cols 0 - 22 (html table indexes)

            htmlArr(j, k) = ObjTr.getElementsByTagName("td")(k).innerText

            Next k
    Next j
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong and how I can fix this?

I have tried to add a counter but I am not sure where it would go

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check the values of `LBound(htmlArr, 1)` and `UBound(htmlArr, 1)`?

Comment: Get the element inside the `j`-loop but outside of the `k`-loop: `set objTr = oHTML.getElementsByTagName("tr")(j)`. Then put a breakpoint after this line and add `objTr` to the watchlist. Also check what the values of `eleColtr.Length` and `numberofColumns.Length`. Ideally, edit your question and tell us what they are.

Comment: Hi, I added the objTr variable and found out it has 22 items as opposed to 23 so having the number of columns not matching was causing the error!

Comment: All sorted now - thanks for your help

Comment: @Izzy888 You're welcome. You may want to add an answer to your question then accept it, once you can.

Answer (score 0):

The lengths of the array dimensions I was using didn't match the table which caused the array not to populate